# Getting the value of a sibling node based on node value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<root>
     <Node>
           <NodeA>1st Node A</NodeA>
           <NodeB>1st Node B</Nodeb>
     </Node>
     <Node>
           <NodeA>2nd Node A</NodeA>
           <NodeB>2nd Node B</Nodeb>
     </Node>
<root>
```

I have an XML document with the above structure. How do I get the value "1st Node B" if all I have is the text "1st Node A". Is it possible to get the node name given a node value in C#?

Comment: In which part of your code did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//NodeA[text()='1st Node A']/following-sibling::NodeB
```

Try something like the above.

Or   `//NodeA[text()='1st Node A']/following-sibling::NodeB/text()` for just the text

I am also including a link to a helper library that let's you define xpath using c# linq-esq expressions 
http://unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-to-Create-Xpath-From-Lambda-Expressions.html